# What interface is this on my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I am trying to find the correct sled and or adaptor for an old hard drive I want to pull files from.  It is a Momentus 5400.2 40 gb hard drive.

What is the interface type of this drive, I have never seen this before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is an adapter on the hard drive, pull it off and you will find an IDE interface.

Comment: I disagree with the off-topic hold.  A better question might have been "What is this port?" to keep people from thinking it was a shopping recommendation.  It is indicative of genuine confusion about a piece of hardware the OP is trying to salvage.  Fortunately, the answer is probably that any USB IDE adapter will be able to connect.

Answer (score 6):

That is an adapter on the hard drive, pull it off and you will find an IDE interface. Adapter after removal below.

[image]

You would need an IDE to usb adapter to read the data on the drive by connecting it to another PC via a USB port.

Comment: Precisely any old 44 pin/2.5 inch pata enclosure

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a
[Parallel ATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA)
connector.

This image comes from Wikipedia. Does yours look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google search about [Seagate Momentus 5400.2 Model ST9408114A](https://www.google.com/search?q=Seagate+Momentus+5400.2+Model+ST9408114A), the first official [Specificiation sheet](https://www.seagate.com/support/disc/manuals/ata/momentus_5400_pm.pdf) shows the interface is [Parallel ATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA).